# Point Read a subdocument Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the Core API and the NodeJS API for Cosmos DB. I am trying to do a point read to save on RUs and latency. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-getting-started) lead me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/item?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-item-read) as my "solution".

However, this makes no sense to me. I believe from similar systems that needs the item ID and partition key, but this makes no reference to the latter to top things off.

By modifying some update code, by mostly pure luck I ended up with what MIGHT be a point read but it gets the full item, not the "map" value I am looking for.

```
const { resource: updated } = await container
    .item(
        id = email, 
        partitionKeyValue = email
    )
    .read('SELECT c.map');
console.log(updated)
```

How do I read just the "map" value? The full document has much more in it and it would probably waste the benefit of a point read to get the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "this makes no sense"? There are only two ways to read: either via a query (where you can do a projection, grouping, filtering, etc) or by a point-read (a direct read, specifying id and partition key value), and that point-read bypasses the query engine. You cannot return a partial document with a point-read - only via query.

Comment: Also: you tagged this as the MongoDB API but said you're using the Core (SQL) API - I changed the tags, accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have seen nothing to indicate that I can not return a partial document aside from lack of evidence to the contrary. It being impossible but not saying so would explain how it makes no sense. I don't like it, but if you are sure that you are correct you should post that as an answer so I can accept it

And thanks for the tags fix, my bad

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to read data: either via a query (where you can do a projection, grouping, filtering, etc) or by a point-read (a direct read, specifying id and partition key value), and that point-read bypasses the query engine.

Point-reads cost a bit less in RU, but could potentially consume a bit more bandwidth, as it returns an entire document (the actual underlying API call only allows for ID plus partition key value, and returns a single matching document, in its entirety).

Via query, you have flexibility to return as much or as little as you want, but the resulting operation will cost a bit more in RU.

Comment: Just to clarify, RU increases with file size regardless of method so point read doesn't necessarily cost less in RU, correct?

Comment: A point-read can be as low as 1RU for a 1K payload (and there is no query as low as that ). RU is more impacted by query complexity than size of document. RU isn’t really tied to bandwidth.

Comment: I believe my confusion is on how payload corresponds to file size. I am under the impression that a file can be 2MB so a pointread would have a 2MB payload but a query to get a single variable from said document which could potentially only result in a 10Kb payload